# How to eliminate bi conditionals?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

p <--> q can be written as

(p → q) ∧ (q → p)

(~p V q) Λ (~q V p)

After this I am confused.

If I distribute Λ over V, I get 
(~p V q Λ ~q) V (~p V q Λ p)
which becomes
(~p V  <strike>q Λ ~q</strike>  ) V (~p V q Λ p)
(~p) V (q)
which means (p → q)

So Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Your "cancellation" is invalid, partly because you haven't expressed the formulas without ambiguity. They should be $((\neg p \lor q) \land \neg q) \lor ((\neg p \lor q)\land p)$ which reduces to $(\neg p \land \neg q) \lor (q \land p)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
(p \iff q) \qquad\qquad\equiv\\
(p \rightarrow q) \wedge (q \rightarrow p) \qquad\equiv\\
(\neg p \vee q)\wedge(\neg q \vee p) \qquad\equiv\\
((\neg p \vee q)\wedge \neg q) \vee ((\neg p \vee q)\wedge p) \qquad\equiv\\
(\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (q\wedge p).
$$